# Possible bug in listing tags?

Tags: bug, tags, status-bydesign

This could be more of a stack exchange bug, but I haven't seen it anywhere but here.

This [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43/is-the-xna-framework-appropriate-for-server-side-programming) is tagged "xna" but the page to [list the tag](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xna) as nothing in it. Has anyone else seen this? Is is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to take a bit of time for the listing pages to update.

Comment: Have seen such issue too on SuperUser when I adjusted tags and then looked on the front page, I also think that it is some kind of server side caching...